# How can I pass each element of a set to a function?

Tags: python, function, set

I have a set with multiple tuples: `set1 = {(1,1),(2,1)}` for example.
Now I want to pass each tuple of the set to a method with this signature: `process_tuple(self, tuple)`.

I am doing it with a for loop like this:

```py
for tuple in set1:
    process_tuple(tuple)
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can use generator expression if you want but loop will be loop anyway.

Comment: I would like to remove the for loop entirely, if possible. I have thought about sequence unpacking but this requires multiple or variable arguments.

Comment: why remove the for loop? would it be a solution for you, to process the set of tuples in your function?

Comment: I don't quite understand your conceptual question.  It seems like you're asking how to pass each tuple of your set, in turn, to your function, without iterating over the set.  Can you please clarify?  Perhaps you want something like the `map` function?

Comment: The map function does not do it for me. Instead of the tuples I am getting `<map object at 0x000002D8C47A4A90>`. And the question is pretty clear in my opinion.

Comment: `map` is not a replacement for a `for` loop, if you don't care (as apparent from your example) about the return value of `process_tuple`. The `for` loop shown is the preferred construct for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is basically "how can I loop without using a loop". While it's possible to do what you're asking with out an explicit for loop, the loop is by far the clearest and best way to go.

There are some alternatives, but mostly they're just changing how the loop looks, not preventing it in the first place. If you want to collect the return values from the calls to your function in a list, you can use a list comprehension to build the list at the same time as you loop:

```
results = [process_tuple(tuple) for tuple in set1]
```

You can also do `set` or `dict` comprehensions if those seem useful to your specific needs. For example, you could build a dictionary mapping from the tuples in your set to their processed results with:

```
results_dict = {tuple: process_tuple(tuple) for tuple in set1}
```

If you don't want to write out `for tuple in set1` at all, you could use the builtin `map` function to do the looping and passing of values for you. It returns an iterator, which you'll need to fully consume to run the function over the full input. Passing the map object to `list` sometimes makes sense, for instance, to convert inputs into numbers:

```
user_numbers = list(map(int, input("Enter space-separated integers: ").split()))
```

But I'd also strongly encourage you to think of your current code as perhaps the best solution. Just because you *can* change it to something else, doesn't mean you should.